# Traversing a non-binary tree

Tags: python

I've made custom class for nodes

```
class NodeTree(object):
    def __init__(self, name = None, children = None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
```

and defined a function that make a tree(a node containing its children nodes)

```
def create_tree(d):
    x = NodeTree()
    for a in d.keys():
        if type(d[a]) == str:
            x.name = d[a]
        if type(d[a]) == list:
            if d[a] != []:
                for b in d[a]:
                    x.add_child(create_tree(b))
    return x
```

The input is a dict with one argument for the node name and a list with its children in the same form as the parent.
The function work fine and I've made method that prove it but I can't find a way to traverse it right and get the height of the tree. I don't know if "height" it's the right term cause I know it may be ambivalent, I need to count the node as a measure unit, like this:

```
                                      parent
                                         |
                                         |
                                     ---------
                                     |       |
                                    child   child
```

The height of this tree is 2, I've tried everything, from counters to tag in the class, everything seems to degenerate an I never get the right height.
How should I approach that?

Comment: Did you check if the tree contains actually what you think? For example by prettyprinting?

Comment: Getting the tree depth by recursion should be quite easy: just add 1 to the depth of the deepest sub tree. Use the "max" function.

Comment: Yes i've print it with indentation and everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

To create a recursive `height` method for your tree that determines the height of the node (that is, the maximum number of nodes in a path from that node to a leaf):

```
def height(self):
    if not self.children:  # base case
        return 1
    else:                  # recursive case
        return 1 + max(child.height() for child in self.children)
```

Other tree traversals can also be done recursively. For example, here's a generator method that yields the names of the trees nodes in "pre-order" (that is, with each parent preceding its children and decedents):

```
def preorder(self):
    yield self.name
    for child in self.children:
        yield from child.preorder() # Python 3.3 only!
```

The `yield from` syntax in that loop is new in Python 3.3. You can get the same results in earlier versions with this:

```
        for descendent in child.preorder():
            yield descendent
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very interesting and precise, I didn't thought about max() cause my tree is not binary and it takes only 2 argument, also I did not know that I could pass a for as argument!        Doing a little research would have saved me a lot of struggle.

Comment: @Janbure Look at `max()` doc and you'll see that it has two signatures: a single iterable argument(like this case) or **n** arguments(so they can be more than 2). You can also specify a keyword only parameter `key`, just like in `sort`.

Comment: @Janbure: That `max` call uses what's known as a "generator expression". They're really handy for creating an iterable object on the fly.